# Porting Objective-C app to Windows. What are the best options?

Tags: c++, objective-c, windows, macos, qt

I have a fully-working audio/video application which is entirely written in Objective-C (with bits of C/C++ and GLSL).

I now need to port it to Windows and I'm wondering what my best options are. I'd like to stay in the C/C++ domain so Java is not an option.

I know that this will be a lot of work but I also want this to be good (attention to detail is very important to me, I subclassed many UI elements to suit my needs).

Currently, I think that I could either port the whole app to C++ and use Qt for the whole UI (I did some small projects with that and found it mostly ok) or I could port the application core and write two different UIs for Windows and Mac (the Mac UI is already there of course).

Has anyone of you done what I'm trying to do and can give any insight? What's the best approach and why?

Comment: I haven't done it, but you can look at [GNUStep on Windows](http://gnustep.org/windows/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

I have almost zero knowledge of Objective-C and macOS UI, but on Windows I think the best C++ OO tiny and efficient wrapper around native C Win32 APIs is **WTL**, based on ATL.

There's a [quality **series on WTL** on CodeProject](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/3841/wtl-for-mfc-programmers-part-i-atl-gui-classes).

In the realm of Windows-specific C++ frameworks/libraries, you may consider **MFC** as well (which offers good integration with Visual Studio IDE), but honestly I prefer WTL: it's kind of more lightweight than MFC.

In addition, there's the cross-platform Qt alternative you already cited in your question.

Comment: No need for the wrapper to be tiny. But if I'm using the platform-based UI approach, would I not go with a more modern approach such as WPF? I used MFC a few years back and even there it felt ancient and not really modern. I need my UI to feel as native as possible.

Comment: WTL seems to me more modern C++ than MFC. Both WTL and MFC wrap Win32 C APIs, in different ways. They can even interoperate. WTL and MFC wrap Windows *native* UI controls like text boxes, combo boxes, list-view controls, etc., but my understanding is that WPF draws its own controls. If you want to use WPF, you should consider C# instead of C++ for the UI. You can still use cross-platform standard C++ for the "back end", for the "core", and use a bridging layer built with C++/CLI between the Windows-specific C# WPF UI and the C++ "core".